# Rails association with almost all other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to deal with "Regions" in my system. 
Almost all other models in the system (news, events, projects, and others) need to have a region that they can be sorted on. 
So far, I've considered a Region model with has_many :through on a RegionLink table. I've never had a model joined to so many others and wonder if this route has any negatives. 
I've also considered using the acts_as_taggable_on gem and just tag regions to models. This seems ok but I'll have to write more cleanup type code to handle the customer renaming or removing a region.

Whatever I choose I need to handle renaming and, more importantly, deleting regions. If a region gets deleted I will probably just give the user a choice on another region to replace the association.

Any advice on handling this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify, why doesn't each of `NewsItem`, `Event`, and `Project` just have a `region_id`? is it not just that simple? Also, does a `Region` have a parent-child relationship?

Comment: There's no parent-child relationship, it seems more like a tag. If I just wrote the region id to a region_id field wouldn't I be losing out on various active_record niceties?

Comment: You want to do it using less models/tables ?? Because if you use :through to associate from one model to other, you'll end up having each intermediate table right? So, you want to reduce that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each News, Event, etc. will belong to only 1 Region, tags don't seem the most natural fit IMO. This leaves you with 2 options:

**Add a region_id field to each model**

This is simplest, but has the drawback that you will *not* be able to look at all the "regioned" items at once - you'll have to query the news, events, etc. tables separately (or use a UNION, which ActiveRecord doesn't support).

**Use RegionLink model with polymorphic associations**

This is only slightly more complicated, and is in fact similar to how acts_as_taggable_on works. Look at the Rails docs on *belongs_to* for a fuller description of polymorphic relationships if you are unfamiliar

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :region_links
  has_many :things, :through => :region_links
end

# This table with have region_id, thing_id and thing_type
class RegionLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :thing, :polymorphic => true
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :region_link, :as => :thing
  has_one :region, :through => :region_link
end

# Get all "things" (Events, Projects, etc.) from Region #1
things = Region.find(1).things
```

Renaming is quite simple - just rename the Region. Deleting/reassigning regions is also simple - just delete the RegionLink record, or replace it's region_id.

If you find yourself duplicating a lot of region-related code in your Event, etc. models, you may want to put it into a module in lib or app/models:

```
module Regioned
  def self.inluded(base)
    base.class_eval do
      has_one :region_link, :as => :thing
      has_one :region, :through => :region_link
      ...
    end
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Regioned
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Regioned
end
```

Comment: I did something pretty similar to your answer. Each Event, etc. can have multiple Regions so I changed the has_one to has_many and pluralized the names. The thing that really tripped me up was not realizing I needed region_id in my region_link table. I also called my polymorphic association "region_linkable" but that's not really important.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the cast about polymorphic associations. They did change a bit in rails 3 though: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association?view=asciicast